# Build failing with cached npm after dependency updates

Tags: angular, npm, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that does an `npm install` followed by angular build and recently I added a caching task to relieve installation which was working splendidly until the developer added a new private dependency of `"runtime-config-loader": "^3.0.0"`.

This may require npm re-install again, however, for some reason the caching task doesn't think it requires a re-install, and so it skips over the `npm install` and then fails at the angular build, most likely because npm did not re-install on the agent.

I disabled the caching task and removed the custom condition `eq(variables['CACHE_RESTORED'],False)` from the `npm install` task, and the build is succeeding just fine.

Why is the cache not recognizing the need to re-install dependencies again? and how do I delete the cache so that npm installs again? As a reminder, when I disable the cache task and npm re-installs again on the agent, the build succeeds - so this is certainly a caching problem.

Here is the ***build YAML***:

```
steps:
- task: Cache@2
  displayName: 'npm Cache'
  inputs:
    key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/EE/Angular/package-lock.json'
    path: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/EE/Angular/node_modules'
    cacheHitVar: 'CACHE_RESTORED'
    restoreKeys: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)"'
  enabled: false
  
steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: EE/Angular
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'install --legacy-peer-deps'
  condition: eq(variables['CACHE_RESTORED'],False)
  
steps:
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm custom: angular build'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: EE/Angular
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run-script build -- --prod'
```

***Old package.json file*** which the build *with* cache was working fine with:

```
{
    "name": "angular",
    "version": "11.2.14",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/cdk": "10.2.3",
        "@angular/common": "^11.2.14",
        "@angular/compiler": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/core": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/forms": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/localize": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/router": "11.2.14",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.8.2",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "9.1.3",
        "@ng-idle/core": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
        "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^10.0.0-beta.1",
        "@ng-select/ng-select": "7.0.0",
        "css-what": "^5.0.1",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "highcharts": "9.1.2",
        "highcharts-angular": "2.10.0",
        "html2pdf.js": "0.9.3",
        "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
        "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "0.3.4",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "11.0.2",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "xmldom": "^0.5.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.14",
        "@angular/cli": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/language-service": "11.2.14",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "^6.3.4",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "4.1.2"
    }
}
```

***New package.json file***:

```
{
    "name": "angular",
    "version": "11.2.14",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/localize": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.14",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "9.1.3",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^11.1.0",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^11.0.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "css-what": "^5.0.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "9.1.2",
    "highcharts-angular": "2.10.0",
    "html2pdf.js": "0.9.3",
    "jasmine": "^3.8.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "0.3.4",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "11.0.2",
    "runtime-config-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xmldom": "^0.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.3"
  },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.14",
        "@angular/cli": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.14",
        "@angular/language-service": "11.2.14",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "^3.8.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "^6.3.4",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "^4.1.5"
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand why you are doing this, but I don't think it's a good idea to cache the node_modules. What about installing the dependencies with [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci) instead of `npm install`? That should be much faster.

Comment: @JSONDerulo interesting, why is caching not a good idea? It was taking about 15 mins for the install so Microsoft is the one who recommended I use cache task, but how I'm curious about your perspective about it :) also what do you mean npm ci? Isnt npm task the npm ci?

Comment: @JSONDerulo ok so i just tried out `npm ci` instead of `npm install` (it was just simply selecting the ci option in the npm task instead of the install option). I did notice improvements, however the reason why i even used caching in the first place is because one of the pipelines for some reason was taking over 15 mins with npm install, so Microsoft suggested caching. I disabled caching on this pipeline and let `npm ci` run, this time the install completed in < 4 mins! great, but i think ill still keep the cache too since it runs in under a minute

Comment: Added an answer. However I still don't think this is the best solution. In past I also experienced very slow npm installs on Windows build agents. Have you tried switching to a linux agent? This has been so much faster for us (down from >10 minutes to < 1 minute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the new dependency is obviously not in the cache. Also the `npm install` doesn't run. So that dependency is missing during build.

To fix it, you need to always run the `npm install`, because you never know if there is a new dependency. Also, after install, if there were new dependencies installed, you should update the cache.

Comment: But that's what I want to do: how to FORCE the install? Because of the condition I have, the install task is skipped. Nonetheless, somehow when I used npm ci and disabled the cache, the next time i enabled the cache the angular build worked somehow, idk what happened but I suppose it now works ‍♂️ also we use linux agents already.